# How do i access AWS SAM-CLI through bash on windows?

Tags: windows, bash, amazon-web-services, command-prompt, aws-cli

I am running Windows 10 and can only access AWS SAM through command prompt but not bash. When i try to use bash, i get a `bash: sam: command not found` error.

If it helps, I currently have installed AWS CLI v2 and have installed it via an MSI file.

Why am i not able to use SAM through bash?

Edit: Yes i am aware that it doesnt explicitly say that you can use bash on the AWS setup guide

> Verify the installation.
> After completing the installation, verify it by opening a new **command prompt or PowerShell prompt**. You should be able to invoke sam from the command line.

**However, I still want to be able to use it through bash. Is there a workaround?**

Comment: https://help.octopus.com/t/aws-sam-cli-in-octopus-cloud-hosted/23729/4

Comment: @UselesssCat that works! when i do `sam.cmd init` or `sam.cmd {any other chain of commands}` it works like it does in CMD. Can you add that as a solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you tried `sam.cmd`?

Sometimes bash don't know how to execute `.cmd` files. Here is a [thread](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/448#issuecomment-578323595) with this problem.

You can try [this solution](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/448#issuecomment-590382892) too:

```
alias sam='sam.cmd'
```